# Should I initialize DOMdocument in the model or controller

Tags: oop, pip, structure, domdocument

I have recently built a script that uses DOMdocument to generate an XML feed of posts from a CMS. I have this working but I would like to integrate this further as an MVC app.

As a base structure I am using PIP. I like how bare bones it is and it should allow me to easily implement my App the way I wish.

The question is should I initialize DOMdocument in the model or controller? The app will generate the file once it has been loaded in the browser, so this makes me think that doing it in the controller is the best approach. Maybe something like below:

```
class Main extends Controller {

    public function index()
    {
        $feed = $this->loadDOMdocument('name');
        $feed->saveDOMdocument();
    }

}
```

The two methods would be declared in the Controller file. Just looking for some advice on the best was to go about this.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use the documentation, that's what I did, and I never used this framework before:

> The View is the information that is being presented to a user. A View
>   will normally be a web page, but can be any type of "page".

See http://gilbitron.github.io/PIP/#views as well. It's the controller:

```
class Main extends Controller {

    function index()
    {
        $template = $this->loadView('main_view');
        $template->render();
    }

}
```

So create a XmlFeedView or whatever it's called by convention in this framework and load it in the controller. And use the DOMdocument inside of the view class.

Comment: It was more a best practice for any MVC framework, there are several ways I could do it, but was curious as to what is the best approach. I won't be loading a view so to speak as I don;t want any output to the screen.

Comment: If you're processing data it's a job for the model layer.